# "The trailer of the film was misdirection ran wild." Is this sentence natural?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

"The trailer of the film was misdirection ran wild."

I have heard the phrase "run wild" mostly in imperative sentences i.e. "Let your imagination run wild". I am not sure if it fits in well with the word "misdirection". Is the proposed sentence natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it must be *run wild*.
In the example
*Let your imagination run wild.*
the word *run* is infinitive.

In the example
*The trailer of the film was misdirection *run* wild.*
the word *run* is the past participle of the verb.

You could think of that phrase as a compact version of
*misdirection [that had] run wild*

Comment: I was thinking it to be a compact version of "misdirection [that] ran wild."